# Ubuntu - Add apache subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, hosts

I have a site (www.site.com, site.com) working fine on my Ubuntu server.

I want to add now a subdomain (sub.site.com) so both work in the same server.

This is what apachectl -S displays:

```
$ apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:80           is a NameVirtualHost
     default server www.site.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site.com.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost www.site.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site.com.conf:1)
             alias site.com
     port 80 namevhost sub.site.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub.site.com.conf:1)
```

In /etc/hosts I have:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 sub.site.com 
127.0.0.1 www.site.com
```

But when I try to access to sub.site.com I'm redirected to www.site.com

I don't see what else I'm missing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---- UPDATE ----

My sites-enabled conf files:

```
site.conf

<VirtualHost www.site.com:80>
ServerName www.site.com
ServerAlias site.com
ServerAdmin info@site.com
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/site
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/home/ubuntu/site">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and the subdomain sub.conf

```
<VirtualHost sub.site.com:80>
ServerName sub.site.com
ServerAdmin info@site.com
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/sub
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_sub.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_sub.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you restart apache services?

Comment: What does your actual VHOST file look like? Maybe add that to question. Also test with another browser to be sure of caching issues.

Comment: It is not recommended to use a host name in the Vhost directive. Use an IP address or * `<VirtualHost *:80>` or `<VirtualHost 123.456.789:80>`

Comment: Right. That change was another desperate failed solution.

Comment: what do you have in the doc root of sub? Also are you using apache 2.4 or 2.2?